# Can I force a maximum upload speed for my network adapter?

Tags: windows-vista, wireless-networking, ethernet, upload, data-transfer

How can I set a maximum upload speed for my WiFi adapter or Ethernet port?

I want to upload as little as possible, and project the maximum I could be uploading (as accurately as possible).

EDIT for clarity: I want to edit my computer's WiFi adapter
EDIT WiFi card type: Dell Wireless 1397 WLAN Mini-Card (the manufacturer in the device manager says its Broadcom)

My apologies for not including more detail.

Comment: Please add some more detail to your question.  Is it a WiFi router or your computer's WiFi adapter that you want to configure?  What's the make and model of the router/adapter?  What operating system are you using?

Comment: I just had a thorough look at my own computer and router.  The best I can find is capping MB-per-month to prevent paying for excess data.  I can't find any way to limit the speed.  What are you ultimately trying to achieve?  There may be another way.